# Java program using JNI cannot find dependant shared objects outside of Eclipse

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, ld, ldd

I have a program that is running inside eclipse right now and uses a JNI call to a shared object I created as a wrapper for another shared object on the system.  This works just fine when I run it from inside eclipse however when I run it from the command line with the following command the shared object that the wrapper calls throws a undefined symbol error.

java -Djava.library.path=[path to library] com.[my name].[program]

ldd does not seem to indicate that any libraries are missing from the shared object.  I have also tried setting all the environmental variables in the shell that I execute it the same as the eclipse environment and it does the same thing.  Any suggestions on where to go from here are greatly appreciated I am out of ideas.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the value of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: I have added everything to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the shell that i am running it from that is in the environment inside eclipse.  I got this out of eclipse using System.out.println(System.getenv()) in my program.  Is it possible that the program sees a different LD_LIBRARY_PATH from within eclipse somehow?

Comment: If you're running Eclipse from the shell in which you checked everything, then I would say no...

Comment: I am not running Eclipse from the shell but I believe it inherits the execution environment from there and adds a few things.

Comment: Hmm, not necessarily. If you modified the environment in the shell, then Eclipse doesn't inherit from it if you run it from a GUI "launcher". Does `System.out.println(System.getenv())` exhibit different values when launched from Eclipse or from the shell?

Comment: They seem to be mostly similar, I just wrote a run script that sets everything except the X display variable to what eclipse uses before it runs the .class file outside of Java so everything in that regard should be the same.  I believe it is something else unrelated to the environment variables in the shell that I run the Java program from.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: [pathtowrapper]/wrapper.so: [path to shared object]libNRSIPS_CUDA.so: undefined symbol: cufftPlan2d

Comment: With the command `ldd libNRSIPS_CUDA.so` you should get a list of the libraries `libNRSIPS_CUDA.so` depends on. One of these contains the `cufftPlan2d` symbol. What if you add the path to this one to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? I mean, running your program with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=the_path java ...`

Comment: So I believe the symbol is in /usr/local/cuda/lib64/lcudart.so.2 so I ran the command 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH java -Djava.library.path=[path to my library] [program]
Is this what you meant?
Unfortunately it still gives me the same error it did before.

Comment: What finally fixed the problem was linking in the cuda fft library into my shared object file via -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcufft. I have no clue what is different but I am very happy that it works now.

Comment: Glad to hear it works now, but the reason it didn't work remains unclear to me...